# Compare two Lists for Anagrams - Java

Tags: java, list, char, anagram

I'm currently working on an anagram solver. I saw a really good post which had one recommendation on alphabetizing the letters of both the user input and dictionary list before comparing. It seemed interesting so I'm giving it a try. Previously I used permutations, but I want something that I can eventually (and efficiently) use to solve multi word anagrams.

I can put both my user input and dictionary into char arrays and sorting alphabetically. Now I need to compare each so I can determine if something is an anagram or not. I thought about taking the alphabetized user input and determining if the alphabetized dictionary contained it or not. I've posted my code below. As you can guess I'm a little confused on the logic of this process. I was wondering if someone could help me straighten out the logic a little. Thanks for any help.

```
public class AnagramSolver1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/dictionary.txt"));
        String line = null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (null!=(line=in.readLine())){
            dictionary.add(line);
        }
        in.close();

        char[] sortDictionary;
        char[] inputSort;

        System.out.println("Enter Word: ");

        String input = scan.next();
        inputList.add(input);

        //Getting a little confused here. I thought about sorting my input
        //then iterating through my dictionary (while sorting it too) and comparing
        //thus far it produces nothing
        for(int i = 0; i < inputList.size(); i++){          
            inputSort = inputList.get(i).toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(inputSort);

            for (int j = 0; j < dictionary.size(); j++) {

                sortDictionary = dictionary.get(i).toCharArray(); 
                Arrays.sort(sortDictionary);

                if(inputSort.equals(sortDictionary)){
                    System.out.println("Anagram" +dictionary.get(i));
                } //end if

            }//end for

        }//end for

     }//end main
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not maintain a `Map<String, Set<String>>` that maps a sorted-character string to a set of strings that are its anagrams. You can update this map as you read words from the dictionary. For example, if you read the word `dog` you would add an entry to the map `"dgo" => {"dog"}` (notice that `dgo` consists of the sorted characters of the word `dog`). Then if you read the word `god`, you would sort its characters to obtain the same `dgo` and consequently amend the previous entry to be `"dgo" => {"dog", "god"}`. You would of course repeat this for every word in the dictionary.

This should allow for quick and easy querying. If you wanted to then find anagrams of the word `dog` you would use `map.get(sortChars("dog"))`.

On another note, I'm going to reiterate what the other answer mentioned, namely that it's important to modularize your code. You should put logically related functions/tasks in their own methods as opposed to having everything in one place. This helps with readability and your/others' ability to maintain your code in the future.

Comment: Thanks but I have a question. How would this work with respect to the dictionary?

Comment: @dave You would load the entire dictionary before hand, via the process I described.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me think about this a little more.

Comment: If you don't want to do the conversion every time you could write a bit of code that read in the dictionary, did this conversion and then wrote the map out to be loaded in another time.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing too many things at once here.  You've got file IO, user input, sorting and the algorithm all in one place.  Try to modularize it so you have a function called `isAnagram(List<Character> firstPhrase, List<Character> secondPhrase)`.  Make sure that works correctly, then have all the other steps figure out how to call it.  This way you can test your algorithm without requiring user input.  This will be a much faster feedback loop.

It's algorithm will work like this:

1. (optionally) copy the contents of the input so you don't mutate the input
2. compare their lengths.  If they're not equal, return false
3. sort each list
4. iterate element by element and check if they're equal.  If they're not, return false
5. if you reach the end, return true.

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion, let me think some more about this.